Visual studio won't load my background pics, why?
Visual Studio says it can't open my file for "graphics/background". The reason it gives is that it is unable to open. Here's what I have done. Can someone please help me?
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Config.hpp>
#include <SFML/GpuPreference.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    Vector2f resolution;
    resolution.x = VideoMode::getDesktopMode().width;
    resolution.y = VideoMode::getDesktopMode().height;
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(resolution.x, resolution.y),"Real Men's Word      Jumble",
    Style::Fullscreen);
    View mainView(sf::FloatRect(0, 0, resolution.x, resolution.y));
    Vector2f mouseWorldPosition;
    Vector2i mouseScreenPosition;
    IntRect arena;
    Texture textureBackground;
    textureBackground.loadFromFile("graphics/background.jpg");
    Sprite spriteBackground;
    spriteBackground.setTexture(textureBackground);
    spriteBackground.setPosition(0, 0);
    cout << "Hello world";

    while (window.isOpen())
        //Handle the players input
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape))
        {
            window.close();
        }

        //Update the scene

     window.clear();

        //Draw the scene
    window.draw(spriteBackground);
    window.display();
    return 0;
}

I have tried everything I have read online so far. I am at a loss. When I try to run it, it tells me, "Failed to load "graphics/background" Reason, unable to open. I have the background file in my graphics folder inside of my SFML folder. It can open everything else just not this. Can anyone please tell me why? What am I doing wrong? What do I need to do? Please Help.

window.draw(spriteBackground); appears  to only happen after you press escape and close the window.

What is your programs current working directory when you try to run it? Is it where you think it is and where you are basing your relative path from? Would it be more reliable to use an absolute path? Have you verified that the file exists in the directory you think it does? Does your program have proper perms to access the file?

"It can open everything else" At least in the posted code sample, you do not attempt to open any other file at runtime, so there doesn't seem to be anything else to compare to. Perhaps this is a simplification of your real code, and your real code does attempt to open another file from ./graphics at runtime. That would be important information.

Put window.display(); before the while (window.isOpen()) loop.

I have the background file in my graphics folder inside of my SFML
folder.

If I understand correctly,   SFML folder means  SFML of <SFML/xxx.hpp>. Additional Include Directories only applies to the header files, not files loaded at runtime.
You need to put the graphics folder  in the same directory  as  the project .vcxproj file.
cout << "Hello world";

window.clear();

//Draw the scene
window.draw(spriteBackground);


window.display();

